# How can I convert auto generated id to uid in Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

 onPressed: () {
                final games = Games(
                    id: user!.uid,
                    pc: pcController.text.trim(),
                    board: boardController.text.trim(),
                    real: realController.text.trim());
                createGame(games);

            },

    Future createGame(Games games) async {
    final json = games.toJson();
    await docUser.set(json);
  }
```

**Here are my codes where the user enters the data into several text fields and saves them in a file called 'games' to the Firestore.**

```
 class Games {
  String id;
  final String pc;
  final String board;
  final String real;

  Games(
      {required this.pc,
      required this.board,
      required this.real,
      this.id = ''});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'pc': pc,
        'id': id,
        'board': board,
        'real': real,
      };

  static Games fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Games(
        pc: json['pc'],
        board: json['board'],
        real: json['real'],
        id: json['id'],
      );
}
```

**Games class I created**

```
  List<String> docGameIDs = [];
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

     getGamesId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('games')
        .where('id', isEqualTo: user?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      docGameIDs = [];
      for (var element in snapshot.docs) {
        docGameIDs.add(element.reference.id);
      }
    });
  }
 FutureBuilder(
                        future: getGamesId(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: docGameIDs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Container(
                                child:
                                    GetGames(documentId: docGameIDs[index]),
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

**Finally, the code where I get the data from Firestore.**

```
class GetGames extends StatelessWidget {
  final String documentId;
  const GetGames({super.key, required this.documentId});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('games');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              '${data['pc']}',
            ),
          );
        }
        return const Text('');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**GetGames widget**

[image]

As seen in the image, the id value created in the file that I defined in the Games class is not the same as the id that the file automatically assigns. However, I used the definition of `id = user!.uid` in the first code so that those ids are the same. In this way, the id created in the file will no longer be the same as the id of the file but will be the UID of the user and it happened.

But for the `.where('id', isEqualTo: user?.uid)` code in the 3rd code to work, the id and uid must be the same as seen in the image. In short, how can I print that automatically assigned short id as the uid (XyyjAZ7FZ8PtWw0vfL7YWXIJAGg2) defined in the file?

Comment: So what do you exactly need, to have the `XyyjAZ7FZ8PtWw0vfL7YWXIJAGg2` as an ID of the document rather than `t7iq...DNzU` which randomly generated?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to have a document ID of your choice rather than the one that is randomly generated (t7iq...DNzU), then you have to create a reference that contains that ID. So in code, it will be:

```
CollectionReference gamesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('games');
gamesRef.document(user!.uid).set(yourObject);
//
```

Comment: I couldn't understand where I should place this code and what should I write instead of 'yourobject'. final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('games').doc(); I tried to write this code instead of the code, but I did not understand how to pull my json file instead of yourobject.

Comment: You have to use this code when you add documents to Firestore. When you're using `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('games').doc()` you're always generating a new random ID. You have to pass the UID of the user to the document() function. And `yourObject` represents the object that you want to add to Firestore. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes thank you. You explained very clearly and I understood. But I think I saw my job in a simpler way. I wrote 'user!.uid' against the 'id' definition under the toJson() method in the Games class. I also defined the user in the Games class as the top one in the first code. In this way, it started to create files with a uid, not a random id.